# Get column name, rowcount, and table_name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a condition, where my table contains a column, which has 5 rows. These 5 rows are table names and I need to execute these table names in order to get no of rows.

Also, I need to retrieve 1 column value in each of these 5 tables.

ex:

```
 Table name: PHP     
    'select all_tables from kbc'
o/p: all_tables
     Customers
     Hr
     PHP
     xyz
     abc
```

I have  customers, Hr, Php, xyz, abc tables. Assuming these tables have some rows.

Also, I need to select company_code column in each of these 5 tables.

Expected result should be:

```
 table_name  rowcount  Company_code
 ---------------------------------
 Customers      10       123
 Hr             20       234
 PHP            50       345
 XYZ           100       456
 abc            05       567
```

I got, table_name and count by using our standard query with `sys.objects` and `sys.partitions`.

Comment: *Need to create it through VIEW

Answer (score 0):

I think the only difficulty here is getting the values of your `company_code`, I believe that this should be a default value on your table, based on your given data. Only way to get the default value is to join `sys.columns->company_code`

```
select t4.table_name
        , avg(t2.rows) AS 'RowCount'
        , object_definition(default_object_id) AS definition
from sys.objects t1
inner join sys.partitions t2 ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id
inner join sys.columns t3 on t3.object_id = t1.object_id and t3.name='company_code'
inner join kbc t4 on t4.table_name = t1.name
where t1.type = 'U'
group by t4.table_name, default_object_id;
```

Comment: In future more number of table_names will be added, So, I cannot hardcode it.  and also there are 100 rows (table_names).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. Also can you please guide me in expecting the same result by creating view as well. In view, I am able to get row_counts, table names by selecting the table name from table 'kbc' using sys.objects and sys.paritions

Comment: i added the output of `print @sql`;

Comment: I think I am too bad in explaining my views. Now, I have to execute this entire part in views, and there are almost 100's of rows and I cannot hard code each and every table name. But they are present in one table column value as mentioned earlier. Sorry if I missed anything. Need Help on this!

Comment: HI, I have tried it, but it is not the default_object_id, hence I got NULL output for the company_code.

Comment: Can you please tell me, if there is any work around for this? Thanks in advance